# access tuneValue from the model object when it is a S4 object - caret, custom model

Tags: r, r-caret

I am using a custom model in caret which basically builds on the vanilla "cforest" method.

To build my model, I fetch the modelInfo for the cforest model:

```
newModel <- getModelInfo("cforest", regex=F)[[1]]
```

I need to implement a custom predict function so I do:

```
out$predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {
    # new predict function which needs the tuned parameters
    best.params <- modelFit$tuneValue
    # rest of the code using best params
}
```

The content of the new predict function in itself is irrelevant. The point is, I need the tuned values from within the predict function.

While the code works perfectly fine with other models, this won't work with cforest because in this case, `modelFit` is a "RandomForest" S4 object and I cannot access `tuneValue`. (The exact error being "`Error in modelFit$tuneValue : $ operator not defined for this S4 class`")

I explored the "RandomForest" object and it does not appear to contain the tuned values in any slot.

My guess is that, since it is a S4 object, the caret code which stores the tuned values into $tuneValue does not work in this particular case.

Maybe I can save the tuned values manually at some point during the fitting process, but I don't know

1 - when I should do it (when are the tuned values selected?)

2 - where I should save them to have access to them during predict

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Here is a minimal code to generate a RandomForest S4 object:

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(20*10), 20, 10)
y <- x %*% rnorm(10)
y <- factor(y<mean(y), levels=c(T,F), labels=c("high", "low"))

new_model <- getModelInfo("cforest", regex=F)[[1]]

fit <- train(x=x, y=y, method = new_model)

# this is a RandomForest S4 object
fit$finalModel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me a while to figure out but it was actually kind of straightforward. Since the model is a S4 object and I want to add informations in it... I built my own S4 object inheriting from this model!

In order to do this, I had to change the "fit" function.

```
# loading vanilla model
newModel <- getModelInfo("cforest", regex=F)[[1]]

# backing up old fit fun
newModel$old_fit <- out$fit

# editing fit function to wrap the S4 model into my custom S4 object
  newModel$fit <- function(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...) { 

    tmp <- newModel$old_fit(x, y, wts, param, lev, last, classProbs, ...)    

if(isS4(tmp)) {
      old_class <- as.character(class(tmp))
      # creating custom class with the slots I need
      setClass(".custom", slots=list(.threshold="numeric", .levels="character"), contains=old_class)

      # instanciating the new class with values taken from the argument of fit()
      tmp <- new(".custom", .threshold=param$threshold, .levels=lev, tmp)
    }
    tmp
  }
```

And now, the model objects are consistently of class ".custom" so I can do:

```
newModel$predict = function(modelFit, newdata, submodels = NULL) {    
    if(isS4(modelFit)){
      if(class(modelFit)!=".custom")
        error("predict() received a S4 object whose class was not '.custom'")
      obsLevels <- modelFit@.levels
      threshold <- modelFit@.threshold
    } else {
      obsLevels <- modelFit$obsLevels
      threshold <- modelFit$tuneValue$threshold
    }
    # rest of the code
}
```

This is great, now my custom model can extend any caret model, regardless on whether it relies on S4 objects, like cforest or svm!